# Is passportjs for client side or server side?

Tags: angular, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I am trying to use passport.js in my MEAN stack app for logging in the user. But I am confused about where do I use passport.js to authenticate the user.

Should I use it on the client side as in angular or else I should be using it in the express app and access profile information through the endpoints?

Thank you.

Comment: Passportjs is a serverside plugin.

Comment: How should i pass cookie to the browser?@asosnovsky

Comment: Read some tutorials. This is beyond thr help you can get here.

Comment: Thanks for the help@asosnovsky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passport.js is middleware that is used server-side with Node.js to implement authentication.  You would use Angular (or Postman if you have no front-end yet) to access profile information stored in the database using API endpoints.

There is an **excellent** video series by Brad Traversy on Youtube that I went through this past weekend that goes over exactly what you're asking about: [MEAN Stack Front to Back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uONz0lEWft0&list=PLillGF-RfqbZMNtaOXJQiDebNXjVapWPZ), where he builds a MEAN authentication app using passport.

Since the code was written 10 months ago, it was a little outdated, but I summarized all of the code-breaking changes in my github repo: https://github.com/Stanza987/mean-auth-app-universal.  You can also see the finished product in action and download my source code if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am still having one issue. For logging user with google-oauth, I kept an endpoint at my express app but when I send request from angular to that endpoint, google's login page is not rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Passport is best suited for servers where all the views are handled by the server. It maybe a **Server Side Rendered (SSR)** app, or using **view engines** like Pug.

But when it comes down to working on a REST api server, you will see clearly that Passport is only usable if you are using strategies that would **not** need you redirecting to a login page and back.

An example of such strategy is `passport-google`, which needs to redirect the client view to google login page then calling a callback url to hand in results.

So if you only wish to use strategies like `passport-local`, `passport-jwt` it is well suited for your REST api that communicates with a client side like angular, otherwise passport is for server-side authentication.